# PostgreSQL DEFERRED CONSTRAINTS and begin end block

Tags: postgresql, constraints, deferred

I have a table with unique constraint that marked as `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;`

Then I execute next query:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO "T" VALUES (1,2);
INSERT INTO "T" VALUES (1,2);
INSERT INTO "T" VALUES (1,2);
ROLLBACK;
```

And everything goes fine. But If i try to execute

```
START TRANSACTION;
BEGIN;
    INSERT INTO "T" VALUES (1,2);
    INSERT INTO "T" VALUES (1,2);
    INSERT INTO "T" VALUES (1,2);
END;
ROLLBACK;
```

I get an error. Why does Postgres force constraint check when exiting `BEGIN END` block? Shouldn't in check constraints at the end of transaction? How can I change this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`END` is a synonym for `COMMIT` as documented in the manual:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-end.html

So in the first example you start a transaction, insert the conflicting rows and do a rollback.

In the second example you start a transaction, then you start another one (because `BEGIN` is a synonym for `START TRANSACTION`) then you try to commit the inserts by running `END`, then you do a rollback.

Comment: The second attempt to start a transaction should have indicated that it had no effect with this warning: `WARNING:  there is already a transaction in progress`.